# Suppressing a processor mismatch warning

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I'm getting this warning when building my project:

> There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "D:\ReferencedProject.dll", "ARM". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight project, which seems to be forced to the AnyCPU target, and some sub-components that are x86 and ARM specific. Since I can't change the architecture on the application project, I want to suppress this warning.

I've searched for a way to do this, and a [few pages say](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/06/processor-architecture-mismatch-warning.html) to set `<ResolveAssemblyWarnOrErrorOnTargetArchitectureMismatch>None</ResolveAssemblyWarnOrErrorOnTargetArchitectureMismatch>` in my csproj file. I've tried doing this on both the referencing and the referenced projects but I still get the warning.

How do I suppress this?

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar warning my Unit Testing projects... finally figured out the warning was coming from the Fakes Project, not my project.  Might want to make sure that the file path in the error is the one you're expecting...

Comment: What is the `Fakes` project? Was it one of references in a unit test project, do you remember?

Comment: Fakes was the Microsoft Fakes project generated for my project

Answer (score 0):

I got something similar when I tried to include sqlite extension to a windows phone 8.1 app on visual studio 2013. What I did was to remove the visual c++ whatever from the references of the project. You may have to remove one of the references in your project that doesn't seem right. Hope this helps.